# How to get the Excel fields(double) as int

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to read the uploaded Excel content, but the following two methods cannot use `reader.GetInt32(1)`:

1. I set the Excel field as "common format" and then input a number 1.
   --> Show InvalidCastException
2. I set the Excel field as "integer format" and then input a number 1.
   --> Show InvalidCastException

So I confirm the Excel field type, and found out it was a `double`.

```
var fieldType = reader.GetFieldType(1);
```

[image]

I have two question:

1. Is this a setting of Excel itself which causes my get type is a Double?
2. How to get the Excel fields as int in my case? 
   Because the content of the fields I should insert into the database must be int.

Comment: try converting the `double` to a `string` first, then parsing that string to an `int`

Comment: Try the concept you explained, I find that it's ok -->
Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(1))

Comment: good to hear :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  try {
    int aaa = (int)reader.GetValue(1)
  } catch {
    //Do something here to log conversion errors
  }
```

Be aware that ADO.NET reads the top rows on the Excel to decide the columns data types. If you have a text at, say, row 200, but the first rows are numeric the column will be numeric and you'll get an error when you read the 200th row.

Also, you can use [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) as Excel reader and avoid ADO.NET. In your case, reading an integer value could be

```
int aaa = sheet.Cells[r, 1].GetValue<int>();
```

Comment: I tried this, but It still show InvalidCastException.
And I will think about the issues you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The following can solve my second problem, but I'm still curious about the first question.

```
Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(1));
```